# Google account permissions "Allow" button grayed out in iOS App using youtube iOS Client Library

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In third party app with  google api objective-c client library integrated,Google account permissions "Allow" button was greyed out after login.
Device - iPad
Platform - iOS

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: We don't have screenshot .Will try to reproduce this issue to get the screenshot.